# Classic ASP Method Not Working When Moved From Win2003 To Win2008 IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, vbscript, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I have just moved an old classic ASP site from a win2003 IIS6 box onto a Win2008R2 IIS7 box, it's all working fine apart from one thing.

I had a little method which would let the user download a CSV of orders, the method is below:

```
sub DownloadOrders()
Response.clear
'Send headers for file name and content type changes
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=orders.csv"
Response.ContentType = "application/text"

for I = 0 to ubound(theorderslist,2)
if I = 0 then
Response.Write("Order No,Date,Name,Address,Town/City,Country,Sub Total,Tax,Shipping,Total,Status" & vbCrLf)
end if
    Response.Write("" & pOrderPrefix & "-" & theorderslist(0,I) & "," & theorderslist(3,I) & "," & theorderslist(5,I) & " " & theorderslist(7,I) & "," & Replace(theorderslist(8,I),","," ") & "," & Replace(theorderslist(12,I),","," ") & "," & theorderslist(13,I) & "," & theorderslist(14,I) & "," & theorderslist(15,I) & "," & theorderslist(16,I) & "," & theorderslist(4,I) & "," & orderStatusDesc(theorderslist(10,I)) & vbCrLf)
next
Response.End
end sub
```

Now if I click the link all I get is a 404 error?  I have even given the directory full modify permissions but still no luck?  Any ideas what else I can try?

As above this has been working perfectly on the Win2003 box for years :(

Comment: Chrome gives me this error message:
The file or directory could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@leen3o: It sounds like the `application/text` MIME type hasn't been defined in IIS. Included in this guide is how you can add it manually: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap

**Update**

Save the following stripped down copy of your `Sub` to `testcsv.asp` on the misbehaving server and access it directly. If the CSV file is produced with no errors, then what ever IIS7 doesn't like must lie elsewhere in your code and you'll need to please paste a little more of it so we can help you debug it.

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=orders.csv"
Response.ContentType = "application/text"
Response.Write("Order No,Date,Name,Address,Town/City,Country,Sub Total,Tax,Shipping,Total,Status" & vbCrLf)
Response.End
```

Comment: I thought this was it, but I added this MIME type and tried others including change the file extension being return but still get the same error! :(

Comment: Seems it doesn't like something as that worked! I'll post up some more code later - Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I was about to ask a similar question but @stealthyninja put me on the right track with his stripped-down test code.

In my case, the culprit in my file turned out to be this:

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", objFile.Size
```

Once I commented that line out everything worked fine, which lead me to [this SO question about content-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040198/iis7-specifying-content-length-header-in-asp-causes-connection-reset-error) which helped track down my real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful articles

http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2008/02/18/running-classic-asp-on-iis-7.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753918%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks but everything in the first link I had already done?  Which is why I am a little confused...

Answer (score 0):

What is the filetype extension on the script that produces the CSV file?

IIS will not serve file types for which it does not have a MIME type registered and instead will return a 404

Additionally as stealthyninja states if the `application/text` MIME type is not mapped then IIS will also not serve the file

Just checked on my IIS7 instance on my Windows Server 2008 dev machine and it doesn't have application/text registered by default as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm mystified... I changed the code to return a .txt file with a MIME type of 'text/plain' which is already registered.  I then mapped .asp to the MIME of 'text/plain' as this is the file extension that the code above is on.  But I still get the same error?

Comment: Except that you are setting the Content Type to be `application/text` in your code which is still not a MIME type registered with IIS by default